# SQL server Instance auto start Failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I install SQL server 2014 Enterprise on my Laptop. It was working fine at first with automatic start of SQL server Service and Agent.
But now in order to login I have to start the service manually, although on configuration manager and services.mcs it shows that it is set to start automatically.

I tried even excluding the SQL server installation path from bitdefender but nothing seems to work

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: What type service account are the services running as?  A built in NT or a specific user?

Comment: I tried both ways but it kept failing. The only last option i resorted to was to create a batch file that starts the services from command line and i put it in task scheduler so it runs on startup

Answer (score 0):

Check the SQL Server error log for related messages.  The latest file is named `errorlog` (no extension) is located in the Log subfolder of the installation path.  Older log files have a numbered extension.

The error log files can also be viewed from the SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer under SQL Server Logs.  This also allows you to view Windows Event Log messages that may be related.

If you need help resolving the errors, add the messages to your question.